# Breslov Kollel In RBS

Tags: eretz-yisrael, kollel

Is there a Breslov Kollel in Ramat Beit Shemesh? Or a chassidus style kollel that focuses on Gemara and Halacha as well as Chassidus (breslov)?

Comment: What language (Yiddish, Hebrew, English etc) and which RBS (Alef, Beit, Gimmel)?

Comment: English and not sure which RBS, I suppose any that have the kolllel I'm talking about - unless of course all of them have that in which case I'd say any